# How to use ontology alignments to transfer instances from one ontology to another one (Abox to Tbox)

Tags: owl, ontology, semantic-web, protege, ifc

I have an IFC file converted to an ifcOWL *(let's call it Ontology A, which is a .owl file)* file containing classes and instances of interest. On the other hand, I have a modular ontology *(let's call it Ontology B, which is a .owl file)* for which the alignments *(let's call it Ontology C, which is a .owl file)* between these two exist.

I am using Protege as my ontology editor and a knowledge management system.

**Now my question is that how can/should I use the alignments** *(Ontology C)* to transfer the instances from *(Ontology A)* to *(OntologyB)* using Protege.

**Things that I have tried so far are the following:**

1-I have tried to create the alignments manually by adding the = or subClassOf relations.
2-Also I have tried http://krrwebtools.cs.ox.ac.uk/logmap/ to the mapping in an automated manner that cannot capture all classes and will only be able to capture all classes consider the same names with different capitalization.

3-I converted the IFC file to ifcOWL using https://github.com/pipauwel/IFCtoRDF

4-I have created a modular ontology with different namings and conventions than the initial ifcOWL.This is because the Ontology (B) is using only a subset of IFC classes. The created ontology (B) will be a subset of 2 or 3 sources of data that are created in form of an ontology for which I will need to pull the instances and query them.